# Specify path to rule file using environment variable or macro?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, build-process

In some of my Visual C++ project files I would like to specify the path to a [rule file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfsbz6cw%28VS.80%29.aspx) using an environment variable or [macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).

I have tried editing the ToolFile element with a text editor:

```
<ToolFile
        RelativePath="$(SolutionDir)\build\tao_idl.rules"
/>
```

But Visual Studio complains that it can't find C:\Path\to\ProjectFile\$(SolutionDir)\build\tao_idl.rules so it looks like it's not expanding the macro.

The same thing happens if I try an environment variable, using either the $(VAR) or %VAR% syntax.

NOTE: The project file is pulled into several other SVN repositories by using the svn:externals property, and not all the repositories that pull this project in use a standard directory structure.

Is this possible?